# How can I convert this time : "9:7.110" to "09:07.110"?

Tags: java, time, time-format

My program obtains two values of times and subtract It.

After subtraction sometimes result may be like this ( Minutes : Seconds . milliseconds ):

```
9:7.110
```

But I want that my program print another one ( if Minutes, seconds or milliseconds contains only one digit, whatever prints ZERO before this digit  :

```
09:07.110
```

Maybe in such format :

```
DateTimeFormatter formatterForResultedPrinting = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("mm:ss.SSS");
```

I store this time :

```
9:7.110
```

in String.

Comment: Where do you get `9:7.110` from? That is a completely broken format.

Comment: What if milliseconds is only two digits? What if it is one?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Should be one or two ZERO before necessary digit of milliseconds, same as with seconds and minutes

Comment: I assume there will always be three digits after the decimal point in the input? (Understanding 12:34.5 as 12 minutes 34 seconds and 5 milliseconds and formatting into 12:34.005 would not make any sense.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got a `String` and the output you want is also a `String`. Why don't you create your own function using simple `String` functions as shown below?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println(convert("09:07.110"));
            System.out.println(convert("9:07.110"));
            System.out.println(convert("09:7.1"));
            System.out.println(convert("9:07.11"));
            System.out.println(convert("9:7a.110"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    static String convert(String str) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        String mm = str.substring(0, str.indexOf(":"));
        String ss = str.substring(str.indexOf(":") + 1, str.indexOf("."));
        String mil = str.substring(str.indexOf(".") + 1);
        if (mm.length() == 0 || mm.length() > 2 || ss.length() == 0 || ss.length() > 2 || mil.length() == 0
                || mil.length() > 3 || !mm.matches("[0-9]+") || !ss.matches("[0-9]+") || !mil.matches("[0-9]+")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid time string");
        }
        mm = mm.length() == 1 ? "0" + mm : mm;
        ss = ss.length() == 1 ? "0" + ss : ss;
        mil = mil.length() == 1 ? "00" + mil : (mil.length() == 2 ? "0" + mil : mil);
        return mm + ":" + ss + "." + mil;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
09:07.110
09:07.110
09:07.001
09:07.011
Invalid time string
```

Answer (score 0):

First *parse* with `m:s.SSS`, then *format* with `mm.ss.SSS`:

```
String in = "9:7.110";
String out = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("mm:ss.SSS").format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("m:s.SSS").parse(in));
```

Comment: The code gives the desired output. If the time had been a time of day (00:09:07.11 AM), your approach would have been correct. However a `DateTimeFormatter` is not for durations, amounts of time.

Answer (score 0):

### Duration from java.time

For an amount of time in hours, minutes, seconds and/or fraction of second use the `Duration` class.

```
    String differenceString = "9:7.110";

    String differenceIsoString = differenceString
            .replaceFirst("^(\\d{1,2}):(\\d{1,2}.\\d{3})$", "PT$1M$2S");
    Duration difference = Duration.parse(differenceIsoString);

    String diffStringWithZeroes
            = String.format("%02d:%02d.%03d", difference.toMinutes(),
                    difference.toSecondsPart(), difference.toMillisPart());
    System.out.println("Difference: " + diffStringWithZeroes);
```

This gives the output that you asked for:

> Difference: 09:07.110

`Duration.parse()` parses an amount of time in ISO 8601 format. It looks like `PT9M7.110S`. Read as a *period of time of 9 minutes 7.110 seconds*. So we first convert your string to this format using a regular expression. For formatting the duration back to a more human readable format we use `String.format()`.

### Links

- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Documentation of the `Duration` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html)
- [Documentation of `String.format` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...))